# Can I execute a remote python script from Mathematica?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, remote-server

Mathematica newbie here. I'm looking to execute a remote python script from Mathematica. Is this possible? I've tried using "Run" but I get numerical outputs that don't make sense (like 65280 for the input Run[ssh IP "local path"]. Is this syntax right or is that my issue?

Comment: `Run` returns the exit code, with non zero indicating some error.  Try `RunProcess`, and note you reall do need to provide the arguments as a list as should be pretty clear in the docs.

Comment: See [the answers here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167962/1806), noting especially the dates because the best option has changed as new features have been added to Mathematica.  Relevant documentation is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExternalPrograms.html), [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html), and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html).  Also be on the look out for [this issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151576/problem-calling-python-scripts-from-mathematica).

Answer (score 1):

```
Run["ssh IP \"local path\""]
```

or, for example

```
Run["ssh IP \"C:\\temp directory\\local\""]
```